# Flutter bottom navigation bar make item with no route

Tags: flutter, navbar

Is there a way that I can make an item on bottom navigation bar unclickable that doesn't route anywhere?

Comment: did not my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

lets say you want to deactivate `deactiveIndex` in your navigation bar. use this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap:(index){
           if(index == deactiveIndex){ return;}
           setState((){_selectedIndex=index});
        },
      ),
```

for more UI representation you can set `activeIcon` for active indices or change the `color` and `style` of reactive index.